# Including a node.js library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use mqtt with ionic in VisualStudio. However, this is the mqtt-Code

```
     function myFunction() {

     var mqtt= require ('mqtt')

     client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost');
     client.subscribe('presence');
     console.log('Client publishing.. ');
     client.publish('presence', 'Client 1 is alive.. Test Ping! ' + Date());
     client.end();
 }
```

I got it from the web. VisualStudio always tells me that require is not defined (well actually i think its because in this context not client-server anymore). Nevertheless, in my Dependencies is under npm -> mqtt available
. I also exported the library as mqtt.js under /lib/mqtt and tried to include it by

```
<script src="lib/mqtt/mqtt.js"></script>
```

but then again i get the message, that the whole function doesn't exist.
I have to confess that i'm new to JavaScript-Development etc. and it's pretty hard to select between what's node.js-topic, js itself or an issue of the IDE. So i could be wrong with my assumption.

Comment: Are you writing for NodeJS, or for a client?

Comment: i try to write a little hybrid app. i have experience in native development so far, but not in the current topic. i use visualstudio because it was recommended if you want to use the framework ionic.

Comment: `mqtt` is a server side library, for Nodejs. By the looks of things you are trying to invoke it on the client. This will not work

Comment: @iamserious I have no idea. It all depends on what you are trying to do...

Comment: I converted it via browserify and linked to it without the keyword 'require', see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#browser
Thank you for your help!